# How can I use req.user outside of app.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been working on a web-app similar to this https://rustbet.com. Here's some code :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, JSON.stringify(user));
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, JSON.parse(obj));
});
```

I'm serializing the users locally.

```
passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
  returnURL: 'http://localhost:80/auth/steam/return',
  realm: 'http://localhost:80/',
  apiKey: '------------------'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
      profile.identifier = identifier;
      return done(null, profile);
      });
  }
));
```

Using steam passport strategy

```
app.use(session({
    secret: '---------',
    name: 'user_session',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true}));
```

Sessions

```
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});
```

And here's how i'm currently using the data

How can I use the req.user object outside of a http request/ EJS template? For instance in a socket.io app that i need. I have surfed stackoverflow and found a multitude of answers but none of them were recent. Also, I'm open to any best practices that i most likely missed.

Comment: `req` means request. So you cant use it without a http request instance.

Comment: passport makes a session where it stores the data I need, how can I access it outside a http request?